# How can I use variables when constructing a URL string?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been given some JavaScript that creates a digital clock to go onto a webpage. This is working perfectly, however, I'm trying to amend it to wrap the am/pm suffix (or Diem in this code) in span or bold tags so that I can style it differently to the rest of the time in the CSS.

I'm sure this would be really simple for someone that knows what they're doing but I'm really struggling.

Any help would be appreciated, the JavaScript is below:

```
function renderTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var diem = "AM";
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
    setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    } else if (h > 12) { 
        h = h - 12;
        diem="PM";
    }

    if (m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    if (s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
    myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + " " + diem;
    myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + " " + diem;
    var diem = document.createElement('span');
} 
renderTime();
```

So, I want to do the same thing, but in a URL style, like this: `http://example.com/example?h="10"&m="42"`

Comment: Where does the AM or PM go in the URL?

Comment: You don't usually need quotes around parameters in a URL.

Comment: What problem are you having? The URL is just a string, you can concatenate the hour and minute to it just like you do when assigning to `textContent`.

Comment: Do you mean to put the `myClock` inside of `diem`? If so, use `diem.append(myClock)`.

Comment: `let url = 'http://example.com/example?h='+h+'&m='+m;`

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the hour and minute to the URL prefix and return that as a string.

Also, your code produces the wrong diem for times between noon and 12:59, since those should be 12PM.

```js
function getTimeURL() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var diem = "AM";
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
    if (h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    } else if (h > 12) { 
        h = h - 12;
        diem="PM";
    } else {
        diem = "PM";
    }

    if (m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    var url = `http://example.com/example?h=${h}${diem}&m=${m}`;
    return url;
} 

console.log(getTimeURL());
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a bunch of comments to your code that'll hopefully make it easier to understand. I also added a global variable that will store your linkText value as it's changed by the function.

```js
// create a global variable that stores our text for the link. 
// Your renderTime() function will update it every second.
var linkText = "";

function renderTime() {
  //grab the new date
  var currentTime = new Date();
  //set diem (whatever that means) to "AM"
  var diem = "AM";
  //get the hours from our current time
  var h = currentTime.getHours();
  //get the minutes
  var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
  //get the seconds
  var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

  //run this function every 1000 milliseconds
  setTimeout('renderTime()', 1000);

  //if the hour is 0, set it to twelve instead
  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
    //else if the hour is any number higher than 12, 
    //subtract 12 from its value and change diem to "PM"
  } else if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    diem = "PM";
  }
  //if the minutes are 0-9 add a 0 before.
  if (m < 10) {
    m = "0" + m;
  }
  //if the seconds are 0-9 add a 0 before.
  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }
  //get our clock element
  var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');

  //populate our clock element
  myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem;
  myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem;
  //not sure why you're writing over your AM/PM variable at the end here, 
  //so I commented it out
  //var diem = document.createElement('span');

  //set our linkText value to be the current hour and minute
  linkText = 'http://example.com/example?h="' + h + '"&m="' + m + '"';

}

//run that thang!
renderTime();
```

```html
<div id="clockDisplay"></div>
```